# How to align labels with inputs using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to align this form

[image]

And I would like to obtain somthing like this [image]

Alway the label takes another place.. and donesn't hold with the input... how can I work with that?

I'm using this code

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4" >
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Rif: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="text" name="rif" id="rif" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Empresa: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="text" name="razon_social" id="razon_social" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Rif.Holding: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nom.Holding:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">PIN: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cartera: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>
```

How could I align that items without losing the format? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have something similar what you are looking for:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="form-group row col-md-4">
      <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rif: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="rif" id="rif" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-8">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Empresa: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="razon_social" id="razon_social" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="form-group row col-md-4">
      <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rif.Holding: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 1</option>
          <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 2</option>
          <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 3</option>
          <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 4</option>
          <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-8">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nom.Holding: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 1</option>
          <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 2</option>
          <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 3</option>
          <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 4</option>
          <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="form-group row col-md-4">
      <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">PIN: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="1" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 1</option>
          <option value="2" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 2</option>
          <option value="3" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 3</option>
          <option value="4" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 4</option>
          <option value="5" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-4">
      <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Cartera: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="1" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 1</option>
          <option value="2" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 2</option>
          <option value="3" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 3</option>
          <option value="4" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 4</option>
          <option value="5" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-4">
      <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Cartera: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="1" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 1</option>
          <option value="2" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 2</option>
          <option value="3" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 3</option>
          <option value="4" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 4</option>
          <option value="5" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class="row" in every div of form-group

```
  <div class="row col-12">
        <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4 row " >
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Rif: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
             <input type="text" name="rif" id="rif" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Empresa: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
             <input type="text" name="razon_social" id="razon_social" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row col-12">
    <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Rif.Holding: </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">Rif 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>

        <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Nom.Holding:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 1</option>
        <option value="2" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 2</option>
        <option value="3" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 3</option>
        <option value="4" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 4</option>
        <option value="5" name="fk_empresaholding_id" id="fk_empresaholding_id" class="form-control">NomHolding 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">

   <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">PIN: </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 1</option>
    <option value="2" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 2</option>
    <option value="3" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 3</option>
    <option value="4" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 4</option>
    <option value="5" name="fk_pin_id" id="fk_pin_id" class="form-control">Pin 5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cartera: </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 1</option>
    <option value="2" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 2</option>
    <option value="3" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 3</option>
    <option value="4" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 4</option>
    <option value="5" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cartera: </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 1</option>
    <option value="2" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 2</option>
    <option value="3" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 3</option>
    <option value="4" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 4</option>
    <option value="5" name="fk_cartera_id" id="fk_cartera_id" class="form-control">Cartera 5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: i did tried this html code and it gave me an inline results 
PS: if you re trying it on a mobile it wont desplay it inline cause of "md"

Comment: yes... but when I want to increase the size of the input from Empresa like I put in the image I lose the format

Comment: i edited the html code to be in the same forme as the 2nd picture just add some width to the inputs you want